# While loop not working php

Tags: php, mysqli

The below function show row count as 4 but its prints only one row. can any one help me what is the error

```
function list_appointments_table() {
    global $db;

    $start_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $end_date   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+15 days'));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM lead_details WHERE next_meet between '".$start_date."' AND '".$end_date."'";
    $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
    echo $result->num_rows;
    $content = "";
    $i=1;
    while($lead_detail_row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE lead_id='".$lead_detail_row['lead_id']."'";
        $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
        $lead_row = $result->fetch_array();

        $content .= '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>';
        $content .= $lead_row['business_name'];
        $content .= '</td><td>';
        $content .= $lead_row['phone_number'];
        $content .= '</td><td>';
        $content .= FormatDateOutput($lead_detail_row['next_meet']);
        $content .= '</td></tr>';
        $i++;
    }
    echo $content;
}
```

Comment: You overwrite `$result`. Rename the one inside your loop. And looks like you should be using a join instead - a query within a loop is generally not a good idea.

Comment: You're using `$result` twice, once to fetch the "lead" and once for the detail. At the end of the first iteration you lost the original `$result` and if the inner query returns just one row you'll go out of the loop.

Comment: You redefine `$result` inside the loop. Use another variable.

Comment: or you could use a `join` statement instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function list_appointments_table() {
global $db;

$start_date = date('Y-m-d');
$end_date   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+15 days'));
$query = "SELECT * FROM lead_details WHERE next_meet between '".$start_date."' AND '".$end_date."'";
$result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
echo $result->num_rows;
$content = "";
$i=1;
while($lead_detail_row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE lead_id='".$lead_detail_row['lead_id']."'";
    $result2 = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
    $lead_row = $result2->fetch_array();

    $content .= '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>';
    $content .= $lead_row['business_name'];
    $content .= '</td><td>';
    $content .= $lead_row['phone_number'];
    $content .= '</td><td>';
    $content .= FormatDateOutput($lead_detail_row['next_meet']);
    $content .= '</td></tr>';
    $i++;
}
echo $content;
}
```

Please above modified code. Notice change in name of variables inside loop.